# Displaying maps in Domino

Tags: google-maps, lotus-domino

The company I work for bought an API key from Google. They are using Domino as their web engine. Placed the code in a page and when generated by using a ZIP code or address etc. It refreshes the page to the original map with pins of the United States. Briefly it will display the map with the entered ZIP code but goes back to the opening map. There is a Domino generated function called `_DoClick`

```
**document._domino_target = "_self";
function _doClick(v, o, t) {
  var returnValue = false;
  var url="/web2/dealermaps.nsf/americas-en-dealerlocator?OpenPage&Click=" + v;
  if (o.href != null) {
    o.href = url;
    returnValue = true;
  } else {
    if (t == null)
      t = document._domino_target;
    window.open(url, t);
  }
  return returnValue;
}**

where:
v=$Refresh
0=HTMLInputElement
t=_self
```

How do I get around this challenge?

Comment: You write what the code does but not what you want it to do instead. Please, elaborate.

Comment: Actually, what you need to do is describe how you placed the code on the page in Domino. I'm assuming that this code is generated from the americas-en-dealerlocator page.  Am I right? What's on that page?  Did you create a button? A computed hotspot? What is being clicked on that is triggering the _doClick call? You mention an HTMLInputElement, but what exactly do you mean by that? What else is on the page? Is there passthru HTML defining a form with input elements on it?

Comment: You are correct as to the name of the page ("americas-en-dealerlocator"). The code was placed on the page as Pass-Thru HTML. We were given code by Google. It words on non-Domino web server.  There is an address field that passes the address to java script provided by Google. The js code is called when the user presses enter.  No submit button is used. Other code on page is our Menu code.

Comment: Not sure I understood... do you want to refresh the current page with a map in it ? then your problem is to pass the parameter entered ? how the Google API expect the parameter ? URL parameter ? did you try to add a computer text with the value of you zipcode in the pass thru HTML ?

Comment: I will try to keep it simple. We bought an API key from Google. The gave us functions and other code.  When the web page come up a map appears with all locations across U.S. pinned on map with a field where the user can enter in an address, zip code, city state etc. After the info is put in the address field and the user presses enter, the code is fired off [ie: onkeypress="handleKeyPress(event,this.form)]. The new map with local locations briefly appears but then the document changes and shows the map of the entire U.S. with  all locations pinned and the address field is blank.